# Problems understanding an encryption and decryption program

Tags: java, encryption

I'm having problems understanding this program. My main doubt is about the secret key. Why do we mention it in the program as it is not secure, like anyone who opens the program can encrypt and decrypt so how is it secured?

Here is the program -

```
 package test;

 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import javax.crypto.Cipher;
 import javax.crypto.CipherInputStream;
 import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
 import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
 import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
 import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
 public class CipherExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //the string key is open here so anyone can change the key and encrypt and decrypt so i didnt understand the use of this program
            String key = "12345678";
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("original.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("encrypted.txt");
            encrypt(key, fis, fos);
            FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream("encrypted.txt");
            FileOutputStream fos2 = new FileOutputStream("decrypted.txt");
            decrypt(key, fis2, fos2);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void encrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
        encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, is, os);
    }
    public static void decrypt(String key, InputStream is, OutputStream os) throws Throwable {
        encryptOrDecrypt(key, Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, is, os);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a simple demo program to me. In a "secure" program you would have the user input the key rather than hard code it. But this is just to show the algorithm I suspect.

Comment: @Floris ok thank you for ur reply can you help me to secure it by using other program key generator as i think i need to write two programs one for encryption and other for decryption but i dont have that much idea

Comment: If you don't really understand what you are doing I would highly recommend that you do not tackle real cryptography just yet. Usually you encrypt things that are in some way valuable - you need to do it right. My advice: get a professional tool for the job and don't make your own.